# Picking Random Item From List (Bukkit)

Tags: java, bukkit

How would I pick a random reward out from this list?

```
Material[] superLucky = { Material.RECORD_10, Material.RECORD_9, Material.RECORD_8  };

            for(Material m : superLucky) {
            if(m == Material.RECORD_10) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "- Enchanted Skull Sword");
            }
            if(m == Material.RECORD_9) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "- Enchanted Skull Helmet");
            }
            if(m == Material.RECORD_8) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "- Enchanted Skull Pickaxe");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would receive a random item from the array like this:

```
int idx = new Random().nextInt(superLucky.length);
Material randomItem = superLucky[idx];
```

Comment: If this was helpful, please consider up-voting or accepting the answer as solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

//create your function that generate random number

```
int rrec = (customRandomNumber())%superLucky.length;
```

use this index to get random reward out.
Note: you may get the same reward again and again as its random.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:

```
// Math.random() returns a double in the range of 0.0 excluding 1.0
int index = (int)(Math.random() * superLucky.length);
```

or

```
// Random.nextInt() returns an integer in the range of 0.0 excluding the specified number
int index = new Random().nextInt(superLucky.length);
```

then do

```
Material item = superLucky[index];
```